# HttpUrlConnection that sends multiple post request in single connection

Tags: java, http-post, persistence, httpconnection

I want to make multiple post calls in a single HTTP connection,

1. I will be sending an `Arraylist<String>` and `httpConnection` objects as the input parameters.
2. Iterate the `ArrayList` and write the request to the server.

I end up getting the below error :

```
Cannot write output after reading input.
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code. I am using to accomplish the above task.

```
public boolean sendToLogsAPI(ArrayList<String> logList, HttpURLConnection conn) throws IOException
{
    try 
    {
         DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
         for(int i=0; i<logList.size(); i++)
         {
             wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
             wr.writeBytes(logList.get(i));
             wr.flush();
             int nothing = conn.getResponseCode();
             String morenothing = conn.getResponseMessage();
         }   
         wr.flush();
         wr.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
      if(conn != null) 
      {
        conn.disconnect(); 
      }
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the javadoc of `HttpURLConnection`:

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for more info.

The problem is you cannot do `conn.getOutputStream()` once you've done `wr.flush()`.

You have to create a new instance of `HttpURLConnection` if you want to send another post request. You can do it in multiple ways. One way is to create a method `getHttpURLConnection()` which gives new connection every time [If you show how the instance of `HttpURLConnection` is created which is being passed to method `sendToLogsAPI()`, then I can show you the implementation of `getHttpURLConnection()` as well.] and modify existing code as follows:

```
public boolean sendToLogsAPI(ArrayList<String> logList) throws IOException
{
    DataOutputStream wr = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try 
    {
         for(int i=0; i<logList.size(); i++)
         {
             conn = conn("<Some-URL>","<API-Key>","<GUID>");
             wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
             wr.writeBytes(logList.get(i));
             wr.flush();
             int nothing = conn.getResponseCode();
             String morenothing = conn.getResponseMessage();
         }   
         if(wr != null) {
             wr.close();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
      if(conn != null) 
      {
        conn.disconnect(); 
      }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Another question I'd like to ask you is why do you want to use the same `HttpURLConnection` instance. Even if you use multiple of those, the same `Socket` (and underlying TCP) could be used. So don't worry about multiple instances of `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Hey i need to  be able to make multiple calls with single Httpurlcollection. This is what I am looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html

Comment: Here is the connection code you asked for:                                              public HttpURLConnection conn(String tempurl, String apiKey, String GUID) throws IOException
 {
  HttpURLConnection conn = null;
  URL url = new URL(tempurl.replace("guid", GUID).toString());
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setRequestProperty("api-key", apiKey);
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  return conn;
 }

Comment: Updated code according to the new info. This will get rid of the error you are getting. If you want to use HTTP persistent connections, follow the guidelines in the link you provided. But you don't need to have same HttpURLConnection instance to have persistent connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your connection in this method so you can't call it twice using the same `HttpURLConnection conn`

You probably shouldn't disconnect your connection here `conn.disconnect();` and instead leave it up to the caller.